# how to create view with sencha cmd in package not in app

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I have an app and many package that required with app, and I will create a view with

> sencha gen view viewname

in package, but raise following error :

> [ERR] Please ensure this command was executed from a valid application
>   directory
>
> [ERR] Unable to locate 'app.dir' config property from sencha.cfg

please help me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: The minimal information we would need would be the directory in which you execute the "gen view" command.

Comment: i run "sencha gen view" in package folder

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_reference.html#sencha_generate_view) that is not possible:

> **sencha generate view**
>
> This command generates a new View class and adds it to the current application.